# Find files younger than a file and print them without their paths

Tags: aix

I am on AIX and I am trying to create a shell that checks all files inside a directory that are created/modified after a particular file and print the result on a txt file without paths, I just need their names.

I am trying:

```
find /sas/data/p1/s5/*spds9 -newer /sas_copiadati/aut_eq_*.cpo >>/sas_copiadati/aut_eq.txt
```

but this way I get their paths, and I don't want them, I just need file names.

I tried
-printf
option but it gives me "-printf is not a valid option"

Any help?
thanks!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `find . -type f -printf "%f\n"` works with regular linux. Check you `man find` to see if `-printf` is an option there. I recall that AIX may have alternate directories that include the GNU version of utilities which would make that code work. Else, you can do `find . -type f | sed 's:^.*/::'` anywhere. Good luck.

Comment: Ask your admin to install gnu-findutils. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha#F

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to use command like:

```
find /sas/data/p1/s5/*spds9 -newer /sas_copiadati/aut_eq_*.cpo -exec basename {} \;
```

`basename` will strip the path and print only filemane.